# Reset Plasma 5.8.6 in KDE

Tags: debian, kde, kde-plasma-5

Hi I am using Debian 9 (stretch) and KDE plasma 5.8.6, and I would like to completely restore the plasma settings. How can I do that?
Previous posts (https://askubuntu.com/questions/109530/how-do-i-restore-my-kde-desktop-to-default) state that for Plasma 5 I should do `rm -rf .kde/share/config/plasma-*` but I don't have any plasma files in that directory.